# jQuery AJAX Not Calling A C# Function In ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

Basically, I am trying to call controller from views using jQuery ajax but it's not calling controller.
What I have to do is passing my token value from registration page to controller so that I will use its value for user registration.

```
< script type = "text/javascript" >

document.getElementById('LoginWithAmazon').onclick = function() {
    options = {
        scope: 'profile'
    };
    amazon.Login.authorize(options,
    function(response) {
        if (response.error) {
            alert('oauth error ' + response.error);
            return;
        }
        GetProfileInfo(response.access_token);
    });
    function GetProfileInfo(token) {

        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Account/ProfileInfo',
            data: {
                token: 'abc'
            },
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });

    }

    function receiveResponse(response) {
        if (response != null) {
            for (var i = 0; i < response.length; i++) {
                alert(response[i].Data);
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
};

< /script>/
```

Here below is my controller code

```
public JsonResult ProfileInfo(string token) {
    return Json("test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

I need to pass the token value from registration page to my controller

Comment: check console for errors

Comment: and it must be  data:JSON.stringify( { token: 'abc'}),

Comment: Please check if there any errors in console. And for URL , use `url: 'Url.Action("ProfileInfo", "Account")'`

Comment: No console error.I have made the respected changes for data and url as told by you now its giving error in console for url (404 not found): "http://localhost:22017/Account/Url.Action(%22ProfileInfo%22,%20%22Account%22)?{%22token%22:%22abc%22}&_=1564121140550"

Comment: add url:'@Url.Action("actionName", "controllerName")' and then try

Comment: @arvind still no call

Comment: hi @shayanitey i jsut now tried you code with `@url.Action...` it worked fine form me. might be some thing else is giving problem

Comment: It is not calling controller.Even result is empty alert says "".

Comment: @shayanitey  are you able to hit other controller/action?

Comment: I am basically integrating login api for external authentication ("https://login.amazon.com/website") because it does not provide code in in C# for accessing token in order to sign up the user through amazon login api.I am not currently able to hit the controller - @arvind

Comment: @arvind I can hit the controller action when user simply fill up the form and signups normally in my website but not through this amazon button i am working on .I just need to pass my token value to the controller through jquery ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this in the controller

```
return Json("test", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

into

```
enter code herereturn Json(new { value="test" }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

and change your js to be like this

```
 $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/Account/ProfileInfo',
            data: JSON.stringify({
                token: 'abc'
            }),
            cache: false,
            success: function(result) {
                alert(result);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Still looking for a solution. Anybody else have a solution??

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i have **solved** the problem.I am unable to call the account controller so i have used my home controller for this purpose.Here below is the code that i have used for calling **controller** :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('LoginWithAmazon').onclick = function() {
options = { scope : 'profile' };
amazon.Login.authorize(options, function(response) {
if ( response.error ) {
alert('oauth error ' + response.error);
return;
}
GetProfileInfo(response.access_token);
});

function GetProfileInfo(token)
{

 var url = "/home/ProfileInfo?token=" + token;

        var request = $.ajax({
            url: url, 
            method: "GET",

            dataType: "json"
        });

        request.done(function (msg) {
            var data = [];
           alert(msg);

        });

        request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {

        });
}
}
</script>
```